# Why my kali linux randomly shuts down computer

Tags: kali-linux

I have hp 8440p and i have just installed kali linux 2016 yesterday.

But all of a sudden the computer just shuts down when i am doing some work what coiuld be the problem ?

This only happens with Kali linux.  It has never happened with any OS i have used.  I even used backbox. It never happened.

I have experienced it when trying to install packages like 
`gdebi` for `skype install` Which i have also failed to do.
Also adding 32bit architecture

Why kali linux ?

**logfile**

```
Aug 23 00:12:41 kali anacron[520]: Job `cron.daily' terminated
Aug 23 00:12:41 kali anacron[520]: Normal exit (1 job run)
Aug 23 00:14:03 kali dbus[502]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service'
Aug 23 00:14:03 kali systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Aug 23 00:14:03 kali dbus[502]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Aug 23 00:14:03 kali systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Aug 23 00:14:21 kali gvfsd[1059]: ** (gvfsd:1059): WARNING **: dbus_mount_reply: Error from org.gtk.vfs.Mountable.mount(): Failed to retrieve share list from server: Connection refused
Aug 23 00:14:21 kali gvfsd[1059]: ** (process:1849): WARNING **: Couldn't create directory monitor on smb://x-gnome-default-workgroup/. Error: The specified location is not mounted
Aug 23 00:14:22 kali dbus[502]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Avahi' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.Avahi.service'
Aug 23 00:14:22 kali dbus[502]: [system] Activation via systemd failed for unit 'dbus-org.freedesktop.Avahi.service': Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.Avahi.service not found.
Aug 23 00:14:35 kali dbus-daemon[1041]: Activating service name='org.gnome.gedit'
Aug 23 00:14:35 kali dbus-daemon[1041]: Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.gedit'
Aug 23 00:15:01 kali CRON[1891]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Aug 23 00:17:01 kali CRON[1897]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Aug 23 00:19:59 kali gnome-terminal-server[1396]: (gnome-terminal-server:1396): Gtk-WARNING **: Allocating size to GtkScrollbar 0xeda1d0 without calling gtk_widget_get_preferred_width/height(). How does the code know the size to allocate?
Aug 23 00:19:59 kali gnome-terminal-server[1396]: (gnome-terminal-server:1396): Gtk-WARNING **: Allocating size to GtkScrollbar 0xeda1d0 without calling gtk_widget_get_preferred_width/height(). How does the code know the size to allocate?
Aug 23 00:20:00 kali gnome-terminal-server[1396]: (gnome-terminal-server:1396): Gtk-WARNING **: Allocating size to GtkScrollbar 0xeda1d0 without calling gtk_widget_get_preferred_width/height(). How does the code know the size to allocate?
Aug 23 00:20:00 kali gnome-terminal-server[1396]: (gnome-terminal-server:1396): Gtk-WARNING **: Allocating size to GtkScrollbar 0xeda1d0 without calling gtk_widget_get_preferred_width/height(). How does the code know the size to allocate?
Aug 23 00:22:23 kali systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
Aug 23 00:22:23 kali systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Aug 23 00:23:07 kali firefox-esr.desktop[1417]: (process:1942): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_path_get_basename: assertion 'file_name != NULL' failed
Aug 23 00:23:24 kali kernel: [ 1003.375960] perf: interrupt took too long (2511 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79500
Aug 23 00:25:01 kali CRON[1992]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Aug 23 00:29:59 kali firefox-esr.desktop[1417]: ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
Aug 23 00:30:12 kali kernel: [ 1411.810238] perf: interrupt took too long (3145 > 3138), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 63500
```

Comment: Could you please describe what happens prior to the computer shutting down, or is it completely random?

Comment: completely  random. I was working in the terminal and eventually screen shows black and shuts down. Sometimes it happens after 10 minutes , 30 minutes, 20 minutes or so

Comment: If possible, please provide system log files. They are located in /var/log

Comment: which file exactly ?

Comment: syslog should be the right log file to use

Comment: Does it slowly shutdown, as if something gave it the shutdown command, or is it like the power was shut off? Maybe it's some hardware incompatibility that Kali's kernel or a driver doesn't like. Do other linuxes run ok?

Comment: it shuts down slowly.. Yes other linuxes are very fine